# error: the following arguments are required: host

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to visualize the result of various sensor data in python

I can see it on raspberry pi terminal like a linux command `python Sensortag2650.py -n 5 -t 1 -T -A -H -M -B -G -K -L -P  54:6C:0E:52:F8:FC`
now i want to see the same result on python shell with same code

```
def main():
import time
import sys
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('host', action='store',help='MAC of BT device')
parser.add_argument('-n', action='store', dest='count', default=0,
        type=int, help="Number of times to loop data")
parser.add_argument('-t',action='store',type=float, default=5.0, help='time between polling')
parser.add_argument('-T','--temperature', action="store_true",default=False)
parser.add_argument('-A','--accelerometer', action='store_true',
        default=False)
parser.add_argument('-H','--humidity', action='store_true', default=False)
parser.add_argument('-M','--magnetometer', action='store_true',
        default=False)
parser.add_argument('-B','--barometer', action='store_true', default=False)
parser.add_argument('-G','--gyroscope', action='store_true', default=False)
parser.add_argument('-K','--keypress', action='store_true', default=False)
parser.add_argument('-L','--light', action='store_true', default=False)
parser.add_argument('-P','--battery', action='store_true', default=False)
parser.add_argument('--all', action='store_true', default=False)

arg = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])

print('Connecting to ' + arg.host)
tag = SensorTag(arg.host)
```

Output :

```
Sensortag2650.py [-h] [-n COUNT] [-t T] [-T] [-A] [-H] [-M] [-B] [-G]
                        [-K] [-L] [-P] [--all]
                        host
Sensortag2650.py: `error: the following arguments are required: host`
```

Comment: Do you want to run the same code on linux terminal? thats what's you mean? 
can you paste full execution command from Pi

Comment: acutually  this will properly run on linux terminal and even data is properly showing but i want to see all the result in python shell window not on linux terminal